# Catch specific exceptions in Python

Tags: python, boto3

My script works fine if I catch all exceptions to an error I was experiencing.

However if I try to limit it to just one exception, this is the error I get:

```
except botocore.ProfileNotFound:
NameError: name 'botocore' is not defined
```

This is my code:

```
import boto3
while True:
    try:
        aws_account = input("Enter the name of the AWS account you'll be working in: ")
        session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account)
        resource = session.resource('iam')
        client = session.client('iam')
        kms_client = session.client('kms')
        secrets_client = session.client('secretsmanager')
        break
    except botocore.ProfileNotFound:
        print('AWS account does not exist. Try again!')
```

If I change the except to:

```
except:
    print('AWS account does not exist. Try again!')
```

The program works.

This is the full error that I am trying to except:

```
 raise ProfileNotFound(profile=profile_name)
botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (jf-ruby-dev) could not be found
```

If I print out the exact exception with:
`except Exception as e then use print(type(e))`

This is what I get:

`The error type is: <class 'botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound'>`.

Yet if I do:

`from botocore.exceptions import ProfileNotFound` in my code and then `except botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound:`, I am still getting this error:

`except botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound:
NameError: name 'botocore' is not defined`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I except this error specifically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to import the exceptions from boto.

```
from botocore.exceptions import ProfileNotFound
```

the exceptions won't necessarily be imported by default.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that. I added from `botocore.exceptions import ProfileNotFound` and in my code I'm doing: `except botocore.ProfileNotFound:` . But the error I'm still getting is `except botocore.ProfileNotFound:
NameError: name 'botocore' is not defined`.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: You're already importing only the exception from `botocore`, not all of `botocore`, so it doesn't exist in the namespace to have an attribute called from it. Either import all of botocore, or just call the exception by name. `except botocore.ProfileNotFound` -> `except ProfileNotFound`

Comment: Thank you! Changing the exception to just: `except ProfileNotFound:` is what worked!